The errorCallback is not logging the error message in testing
I am new to coding and making a react app. This is part of the code to get the geolocation
  const getLocation = () => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {
      });
    } 
  };

  const errorCallback = (error) => {
    switch (error.code) {
      case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
        setErrorMessage(error.message);
        break;
      default: 
        setErrorMessage("");
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {errorMessage && <p>{errorMessage}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

Then i tests this part with
import { render, screen, waitFor, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App'; // Adjust the import according to your file structure

// Mock the geolocation API
global.navigator.geolocation = {
  getCurrentPosition: jest.fn()
};

test('handles geolocation error', async () => {
  // Mock the getCurrentPosition function to return an error asynchronously
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition.mockImplementationOnce((success, error) => {
      error({
        code: 1,
        message: "User denied geolocation prompt"
      });
  });

  render(<App />);

  // Wait for the error message to appear
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(screen.getByText("User denied geolocation prompt")).toBeInTheDocument();
  }, { timeout: 1000 });
});

So the test case is setting the error to be code 1, which is the permission denied error. However, the switch function is going to the default case instead of the permission denied case.

Can you clean up your code to only the relevant parts. There's extra noise that makes it harder to help. If you remove the set timeout, does it work?

It is the same issue. The switch function always fires the default case.

You may not be passing in an error.code here: if (navigator.geolocation) {       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, {       });     } 

The correct passing of the error is like this   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition.mockImplementationOnce((success,error) =>     Promise.resolve(       error({         code: 1,         message: "User denied geolocation prompt",         PERMISSION_DENIED: 1       })

The correct passing of the error is like this:
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
  .mockImplementationOnce((success, error) => Promise.resolve(
    error({
      code: 1,
      message: "User denied geolocation prompt",
      PERMISSION_DENIED: 1
    })
  ));

